# Does using YouTube LiveStreamingAPI(LiveChatMessages) violate the Terms of Service?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I try to get video's live chat, but [LiveChatMessages API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list) returns the following user's information.

- items[n].snippet.authorChannelId

[YouTube Terms of Service](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms) prohibits the acquisition of information that may identify an individual.

> Permissions and Restrictions

> 4. collect or harvest any information that might identify a person (for example, usernames), unless permitted by that person or allowed under section (3) above;

What should i do?

1. can't use LiveChatMessages API. (Who can use it?)
2. If I don't refer to snippet.authorChannelId, I can use LiveChatMessages API.
3. I don't care about anything.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be more of a legal question relating to the google TOS.  OP should contact google or a lawyer.    SO can only help you with programming re questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing to worry about here: only obtaining from the API the property [`snippet.authorChannelId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages#snippet.authorChannelId) does not violate any TOS specs, since this property is nothing more than the chat poster's ID:

> [**`snippet.authorChannelId`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages#snippet.authorChannelId) (string)
>
> The ID of the user that authored the message. This field is only filled for the following message types:
>
> - If the message type is `textMessageEvent`, the property value identifies the user that wrote the message.
> - If the message type is `fanFundingEvent`, the property value identifies the user that funded the broadcast.
> - If the message type is `messageDeletedEvent`, the property value identifies the moderator that deleted the message.
> - If the message type is `newSponsorEvent`, the property value identifies the user that just became a sponsor.
> - If the message type is `userBannedEvent`, the property value identifies the moderator that banned the user.

Having an user ID -- that is that user's ID as assigned to him/her by YouTube -- does not fall under the spec you've quoted.

You may very well use that ID for to obtain the *publicly available data* of the respective user (i.e. YouTube channel): just call for the [`Channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) API endpoint passing to it that ID as the parameter [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#id) for to obtain (again *only public*) data about that channel in the form of a [`Channel resource`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#resource).

Otherwise is good to be attentive at complying with YouTube's [DTOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies) specifications and is quite advisable to be familiar with the content of that document.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I understand that there is no problem using the target element.
I will carefully check and understand [TOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service), [DTOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies).